# (SQL BigQuery) Using Lag but data contains missing months

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, lag, sql-date-functions

I have the following table with monthly data. But we do not have the third month.

| DATE | FREQUENCY |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 6000 |
| 2021-02-01 | 4533 |
| 2021-04-01 | 7742 |
| 2021-05-01 | 1547 |
| 2021-06-01 | 9857 |

I want to get the frequency of the previous month into the following table.

| DATE | FREQUENCY | PREVIOUS_MONTH_FREQ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 6000 | NULL |
| 2021-02-01 | 4533 | 6000 |
| 2021-04-01 | 7742 | NULL |
| 2021-05-01 | 1547 | 7742 |
| 2021-06-01 | 9857 | 1547 |

I want the 2021-04-01 record to have NULL for the PREVIOUS_MONTH_FREQ since there is no data for the previous month.

I got so far as...

```
SELECT DATE, 
       FREQUENCY, 
       LAG(FREQUENCY) OVER(ORDER BY DATE) AS PREVIOUS_MONTH_FREQ
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CASE expression to check if the previous row contains data of the previous month:

```
SELECT DATE, 
       FREQUENCY, 
       CASE WHEN DATE_SUB(DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = LAG(DATE) OVER(ORDER BY DATE)
            THEN LAG(FREQUENCY) OVER(ORDER BY DATE)
       END AS PREVIOUS_MONTH_FREQ
FROM Table1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3db81c2f98c5673a5a9dfbe4f4544f52).

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, you can use a `RANGE` window specification.  This only trick is that you need a number rather than a date:

```
select t.*,
       max(frequency) over (order by date_diff(date, date '2000-01-01', month)
                            range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding
                           ) as prev_frequence
from t;
```

The `'2000-01-01'` is an arbitrary date.  This turns the date column into the number of months since that date.  The actual date is not important.